# difference between 'first grader' and 'first year student'

Tags: word-usage

I'm sorry I don't have any context. But I'm just wondering if there's a difference between 'first grader' and 'first year student'.

Comment: In the US, we don't hear people referring to children 5 and 6 years old as "first year students". They are "first graders".   A "first year student" is usually about 18 years old and is entering university, or is someone who has finished university and is now in the first year of a doctorate program or entering medical school.  "First graders" are children.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any context, I'm afraid, these are **not** the same phrases.

Because, first grader means (US) [a child in the first grade](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/first-grader) but when you say 'First year student' it could be the first year of a professional degree as well. Say -- A first year student of arts/science/commerce whatever...

Answer (score 0):

First grade is the first class in elementary school. Children in these classes are usually between 6 and 7 years old.

The term 'first year student' can be used for all people who are in first class (primary, secondary school, etc.).

Conclusion: Without any context, there is a difference.